# How do I revert back to IE8 on Windows7 after uninstalling IE10?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

We recently pushed out a test package of IE10 for a small pilot group of Windows7 users.  IE10 was not compatible with some software for a user.  User requested reverting back to IE8.  We uninstalled IE10, but IE8 is not an option for installation.

Does anyone know how to reinstall IE8 on Windows7?

Comment: You don't. You uninstall IE10.  You can do that in `Add/Remove Programs` provided you didn't remove the ability for Windows to do so.  If you did that you will have to reinstall Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Start Menu>Control Panel>Programs>Programs and Features**
2. Select **View Installed Updates** in the left pane
3. Find **Windows Internet Explorer 10** on the right and select
   **Uninstall**

This will revert yo to IE9 or IE8 (if you didn't upgraded from IE8 to IE9)

---

If you don't have **Windows Internet Explorer 10** under **View Installed Updates**, than you can force uninstall via Command Prompt

Run cmd.exe as Administrator

Enter the following:

> FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c “cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart”

Just press **OK** if any error pops up and when you can see the blinking cursor next to `C:/Windows/System32`, restart computer

If this reverted you to IE9, than just repeat steps 1 to 3 but this time uninstall Internet Explorer 9 and you should be back to IE8

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall them through Windows Updates

```
Control Panel > Programs > Uninstall a Program > View Installed Updates
```

Find Internet Explorer 10 and uninstall it, you will mostly likely need to reboot, but then next time you go in there, you will see Internet Explorer 9, do the same and uninstall that and reboot. You should be back to IE8 after that!